# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ‘date’ in ‘field list’

Tags: magento

Magento Platform version 1.5.0.1

I have recently move my website from an old server to a new one and seem to be getting the above error when trying to add, update or duplicate products. Although at first they were still being published to the site they now are not showing at all.

I have tried the following:

1) Cleared Cache - no joy
2) Reindex Data - no joy but the Category Flat Data and Product Flat Data is constantly reindexing and I can not reindex (this could be the issue)??
3) Deleted the LOCK files in /var/locks folder - no joy

I am really in a pickle here and would really love some help please.

Paul

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on 1.5.0.1 - A recent data import had broken something and I couldn't index.

When I looked into it I found that the 'date' column of the 'catalog_product_index_website' table had been renamed to 'website_date' (as it is named in later versions of magento)

I dropped the table and re-created it from a back up:

```
CREATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_website` (
  `website_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `rate` float(12,4) unsigned DEFAULT '1.0000',
  PRIMARY KEY (`website_id`),
  KEY `IDX_DATE` (`date`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CATALOG_PRODUCT_INDEX_WEBSITE` FOREIGN KEY (`website_id`) REFERENCES `core_website` (`website_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

That sorted the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem when I upgrade magento from 1.4.1 to 1.7.2 
This problem came from Amasty Extension.
Fix: Try to turn off some Amasty Extension on your site then check it again.
Hope it's useful for someone.